# How to filter an array for a JSON response data in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array called `ReservationResponse`. This array is a successful response from an API call. The following example highlights how it is being retrieved

```
const ReservationResponse = await this.service.getReservation(this.username.value);
```

The JSON response looks more like

```
[
 {
  "id":150,
  "end_time":"2023-03-03T22:00:00Z",
  "start_time":"2023-03-03T16:00:00Z"
 },
 {
  "id":160,
  "end_time":"2023-03-06T12:00:00Z",
  "start_time":"2023-03-06T09:00:00Z"
 }
]
```

The response is displaying the data from the start date of the reservations. The start date is when a user creates a reservation. There is a change request to show the data from today's date rather than the first reservation date.

I am comfortable doing a backend change as requested, and that will require a change to the front end as well, and that is where I am struggling.

Is there a way that I can filter and get the data from the response based on today's date?

PS: I am new to Angular.

Comment: i am trying to add the code like this result = ReservationResponse.filter((obj) => obj.start_time.getTime());  not sure its the right filter or not

Comment: The ReservationResponse should display from today's date onwards

Comment: Do you want sort the array?

Comment: i want to diplay data by today date not the sorting the array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the current date in ISO-8601 date format, because your JSON response use that format.
Try this

```
let today = new Date().toISOString();

const ReservationResponse = await this.service.getReservation(this.username.value).filter(r => r.start_time === today);
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: actually when i used your code first i am getting a compile error   if i use the toISOSTringout it get compile but no data() withReservationResponse = 
                        ReservationResponse.filter(d => d.start_time===todayDate);

Comment: getting this error message This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'Date' and 'number' have no overlap.

Comment: with a slight change your solution works fine . thank you .